# Variable not actually set when retrieving from Firebase

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the number of children in this section of my Firebase Database, however the variable that I am setting is only locally set. Interestingly, the first print statement, prints two (which is the number I want), however, the second print statement prints zero. How can I make the function return the correct value. Thank you for the help.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    var forReturn = 0
    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    databaseRef.child("gameNumber").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        forReturn = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)
        print(forReturn)
    })
    print(forReturn)
    return forReturn
}
```

This prints repeating twos and zeros.

Comment: That's probably an asynchronous block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare forReturn in the class's scope and call the firebase method somewhere else. Then reload the table when you reach inside the firebase completion handler.

```
//In your viewDidLoad or wherever you think suitable    
let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
databaseRef.child("gameNumber").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    DisptachQueue.main.async {
        forReturn = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)
        self.tableView.reloadData() //take an outlet of tableView
        print(forReturn)   
    }
})
```

Comment: Is that asynchronous? If so, you should probably use `DispatchQueue.main.async { }`

Comment: yes it is asynchronous, we can use dispatchqueue here too

Comment: how would you implement that?

Comment: @joshLor - add any UI update code - like `tableView.reloadData()` inside the `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` block

Comment: DispatchQueue.main is a must when your UI operations are in multiple threads and you want them to run in the main thread... I am adding the code above, thanks @Pierce for pointing that out.

Comment: In future if you come at a situation where the UI is not updating/lagging then use this @joshLor

Comment: It still isn't working. I think it is because of my implementation. The code in the snapshot runs after the second print code. Can you be a little more specific? @Naresh

Comment: @joshLor the code in databaseRef.child(). observers ngleEvent() method is asynchronous. It runs in another thread. So, you have to reload the table by the method <tableview's outlet>.reloadData(). But as you have to call it when the databaseRef.child(). observers ngleEvent() call get completed, you have to place it inside the method's callback. Which means below the first print(forReturn) statement.

Comment: @joshLor you to place the method call databaseRef.child().observers ngleEvent() in your controller's viewDidLoad(). Not in the numberOfRowInSection method.

Comment: why if I am not trying to retrieve the data then?

Comment: Let's save our time, upload your code on ideone and send me the url.